# Conection String do Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação C# Asp Net com MVC em um Banco SQL SERVER no provedor de acesso KingHost, porém não consigo fazer com que a applicação conect ao banco do KH, dá um erro de Windows, alguém poderia me ajudar.

Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/padraomvc'.
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

> Detalhes da Exceção: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

Erro de Origem:

> Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

Rastreamento de Pilha:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo
>   especificado]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao
>   estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou
>   não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e
>   se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Não é possível
>   localizar uma instalação de Local Database Runtime. Verifique se o SQL
>   Server Express está instalado corretamente e se o recurso Tempo de
>   Execução de Banco de Dados Local está habilitado.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager) +907

Comment: Você leu a mensagem de erro? "_**O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas**_".

Comment: A questão é que configuro o Banco do KH na minha maquina pelo IP passado, a aplicação rodando em LocalHost, e gravando no banco da KH e funciona normal, porem quando mando a aplicação para o ftp e roda na WEB, ele tenta conectar no banco da kh e aí dá esse erro.

Comment: Talvez o seu host web não esteja permitindo chegar até o endereço da KH para conectar ao banco

Answer (score 0):

Achei o problema, como usava o identity ele cria as tabelas e um outro banco, agora criei as tabelas no meu banco e apontei a conexão padrão dele pro banco correto e funcionou